# Writing an action to trigger camera shutter via bluetooth button

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to use a flic button with the 'send intent' function to trigger the camera shutter button universally in camera apps (snapchat, Instagram, etc).

I've figured out how to use it to open the camera but not to just activate the shutter (similar to the way that the volume buttons act as shutter buttons)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you need a custom camera or open the standard camera intent?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want the button to mimick the press of a volume button when a camera app is open. I just started learning about all this, so I'm 110% novice still.